# I am not sure about correct way to export PATH

Tags: bash, path, profile, etc

I have Java and Springboot cli added to `PATH` however, when `source /etc/profile` it gives error.

And on restarting **PC**, `BASH` is not loading.

My export in `/etc/profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-2.el8_5.x86_64
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar

export SPRING_HOME=/home/jacobd/spring-2.7.0/bin
export PATH=$SPRING_HOME/bin
```

Can anyone guide, where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no actual error in the code that you show that would provoke `source` to report an error, so it's unfortunate that you don't mention what that specific error message says.  The file does, however, contain a problematic typo (?) that would make it difficult to use the shell after sourcing it.

On that last line, you throw away the old value of `PATH` and replace it with `$SPRING_HOME/bin`.   The effect of this is that the shell will only find external executables in that single path while ignoring all the standard paths.

I'm assuming you want to *append* that new path to the `PATH` variable in a similar way as is done on the 2nd line of the code that you show, rather than replace the old value.

```bash
PATH=$PATH:$SPRING_HOME/bin
```

Note that after exporting a variable, it remains exported, so there's no need to export it again (unless you explicitly unset it).